# How to access files within a Windows server from a Laravel application in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, windows, laravel, ubuntu, ssh

I need to connect through ssh from a Laravel application hosted in Ubuntu to a Windows server where I want to retrieve some files in order to use them within my application.

The Laravel Application is hosted in Ubuntu with nginx 1.14 and using PHP 7.3.6 and Laravel 5.8.

The files I need to use (By 'use' I mean read, edit, download and upload) in Laravel need to stay in that Windows server because moving them to Linux would be too much of a hassle for the people who create these files (Excel worksheets, text files, csv files) and for me because I would have to configure the samba shared folders on every PC here.

I have tried using ssh to connect to the Windows server and it shows the login prompt but no credentials are working (It's within a domain and I've tried with 'domain\username' but to no effect :( ).

**Summary**

- Files in Windows server: xlsx, csv, txt
- Operations: read, edit, donwload, upload.
- Laravel application is hosted in Ubuntu.
- Can't connect through ssh from Ubuntu to Windows server.
- Ubuntu server configuration:

  - Ubuntu 18.04
  - Nginx 1.14.0
  - Laravel 5.8
  - PHP 7.3.6

My login attempts:

```
sys@server:~$ sudo ssh arebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx
arebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

arebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

arebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx port 22:2: Too many attempts.
Disconnected from xx.xx.xx.xx port 22


sys@server:~$ sudo ssh AzureAD\arebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx
AzureADarebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

AzureADarebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

AzureADarebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx port 22:2: Too many attempts.
Disconnected from xx.xx.xx.xx port 22


sys@server:~$ sudo ssh domain\arebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx
domainarebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

domainarebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

domainarebollar@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx port 22:2: Too many attempts.
Disconnected from xx.xx.xx.xx port 22
```

Comment: Would flysystem-smb be something you could use?
https://packagist.org/packages/robgridley/flysystem-smb

Comment: @stokoe0990 I'll give it a try. :D Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer for anyone who is struggling with an issue like mine.

I finally solved this using ftp, accesing the files like this:

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->files($this->filePath.$filename)
```

I added a ftp local disk in config/filesystems.php:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

...

        'ftp' => [
            'driver'   => 'ftp',
            'host'     => env('FTP_HOST'),
            'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
        ],
```

And finally added the ftp parameters to the .env file and ran:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Hope this helps someone else. :)